# What is the Visual Studio Development Server equivalent of the Apache Access Log?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, logging

Coming from a PHP/Apache background I'm looking for the equivalent of the Access Log when I'm developing ASP.NET MVC applications in Visual Studio 2008. On the Unix box I'm used to tailing the access_log to get an real time view of which requests is send to the web server:

```
tail -f access_log
```

I'm currently looking into ASP.NET Traces. It sort of does the trick, but I would like to know of any alternatives. For instance where is the "access_log" in the Visual Studio Development Server?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question directly, since I use IIS for development, but I never thought about using the web server log for development. I always use the Firefox extension Firebug, but other tools like Fiddler are also fine. They give you a lot more information than a single line with timestamp, url, status code or whatever. You see the whole HTTP request, including cookies, all the cache headers and even the actual content, nicely parsed (e.g. JSON data)

Comment: Firebug is actually a good idea, I have used in the past to debug similar problems. But the problem I'm debugging at the moment, happens at the exact moment I start the Visual Studio debug session, which means that the Net console in Firebug is not active.

Comment: Fiddler is very cool - still it doesn't explicitly says what the web server is being requested. It also takes some tweaking to get it to work with localhost and Firefox. But as I said very cool! Thanks!

Comment: Assuming the error happens in managed code, maybe breaking at all exceptions helps. (Ctrl+Alt+E, and select the managed exceptions)

Comment: I get an exception, so that's not an issue. Also I think I have gotten the original problem solved. Now I'm just curious to get some more answers on the original question. Really appreciate your input!